# Getting 400 error while creating "Web Token" when hitting enterprises.webTokens.create endpoint to use iframe in EMM console

Tags: iframe, asp.net-core-6.0, android-management-api

We are getting 200  success while hitting endpoints like create signup URL, create enterprise, create enrollment token etc. through API Explorer or Postman. But while we are trying to hit the "create web token" endpoint we are getting 400 error.

We are implementing Google Android Management API. Finally, we are proceeding for implementing iframe which required the web token as it's carrier. But we are failing to do so.

For your reference:

**enrollmentTokens.create endpoint Link below:**
https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.enrollmentTokens/create

In the API explorer we are providing
parent = enterprises/LC00x1u8p0 and selecting Google OAuth 2.0 credentials.
With this much information API Explorer giving 200 success message.

**enterprises.webTokens.create endpoint Link below:**
https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.webTokens/create

In the API explorer we are providing
parent = enterprises/LC00x1u8p0 and selecting Google OAuth 2.0 credentials.
With this the same information API Explorer giving 400 error. I have posted the error message and unable to understand where is the error coming.

**Is our console cloud project need any special supplement for giving access to web token? or what exactly is the lacking that giving this 400 error?**

We are failing to understand the error message. **Please check the below response.**

```
​{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "domain: \"gdata.CoreErrorDomain\"\ncode: \"INVALID_VALUE\"\nargument: \"tokenSpec.parent\"\ndebug_info: \"code: INVALID_VALUE\\nhttp status: 400\\narguments: [tokenSpec.parent]\\nvalue: \\ncause: com.google.wireless.android.vending.enterprise.common.exceptions.InvalidParameterException: EnterpriseException{httpStatus=400, code=gdata.CoreErrorDomain.INVALID_VALUE, arguments=[tokenSpec.parent]}\\n\\tat com.google.wireless.android.vending.enterprise.common.exceptions.InvalidParameterException$Builder.build(InvalidParameterException.java:60)\\n\\tat com.google.wireless.android.vending.enterprise.business.EmbeddedUiServiceImpl.validate(EmbeddedUiServiceImpl.java:173)\\n\\tat com.google.wireless.android.vending.enterprise.business.EmbeddedUiServiceImpl.createWebToken(EmbeddedUiServiceImpl.java:123)\\n\\tat com.google.wireless.android.vending.enterprise.actions.mdmapi.EnterpriseActions$CreateWebTokenAction.execute(EnterpriseActions.java:360)\\n\\tat com.google.apps.framework.request.impl.InterceptorInvocation$Rpc.beforeProceed(InterceptorInvocation.java:147)\\n\\tat com.google.apps.framework.request.impl.InterceptorInvocation.proceed(InterceptorInvocation.java:158)\\n\\tat com.google.apps.framework.request.impl.RpcDispatcher.proceed(RpcDispatcher.java:136)\\n\\tat com.google.apps.framework.request.impl.RpcDispatcher.proceed(RpcDispatcher.java:42)\\n\\tat com.google.apps.framework.request.impl.AbstractDispatcher.doExecuteChainInternal(AbstractDispatcher.java:503)\\n\\tat com.google.apps.framework.request.impl.AbstractDispatcher.doExecuteChain(AbstractDispatcher.java:497)\\n\\tat com.google.apps.framework.request.impl.AbstractDispatcher.execute(AbstractDispatcher.java:331)\\n\\tat com.google.apps.framework.request.impl.AbstractDispatcher.executeAsync(AbstractDispatcher.java:254)\\n\\tat com.google.apps.framework.request.impl.RpcDispatcher.handleRpc(RpcDispatcher.java:126)\\n\\tat com.google.apps.framework.request.impl.RpcScopedHandlerFactoryImpl.run(RpcScopedHandlerFactoryImpl.java:276)\\n\\tat com.google.apps.framework.request.impl.RpcScopedHandlerFactoryImpl$2.handleRequest(RpcScopedHandlerFactoryImpl.java:126)\\n\\tat com.google.net.rpc3.impl.server.RpcServerInterceptor2Util$RpcApplicationHandlerAdaptor.handleRequest(RpcServerInterceptor2Util.java:82)\\n\\tat com.google.net.rpc3.impl.server.RpcServerInternalContext.runRpcInApplicationWithCancellation(RpcServerInternalContext.java:672)\\n\\tat com.google.net.rpc3.impl.server.RpcServerInternalContext.lambda$runRpcInApplication$0(RpcServerInternalContext.java:637)\\n\\tat io.grpc.Context.run(Context.java:536)\\n\\tat com.google.net.rpc3.impl.server.RpcServerInternalContext.runRpcInApplication(RpcServerInternalContext.java:637)\\n\\tat com.google.net.rpc3.impl.server.RpcServerChannel$4.apply(RpcServerChannel.java:1026)\\n\\tat com.google.net.rpc3.impl.server.RpcServerChannel$4.apply(RpcServerChannel.java:996)\\n\\tat com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractTransformFuture$TransformFuture.doTransform(AbstractTransformFuture.java:253)\\n\\tat com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractTransformFuture$TransformFuture.doTransform(AbstractTransformFuture.java:243)\\n\\tat com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractTransformFuture.run(AbstractTransformFuture.java:124)\\n\\tat com.google.common.context.ContextRunnable.runInContext(ContextRunnable.java:89)\\n\\tat com.google.common.context.ContextRunnable$1.run(ContextRunnable.java:78)\\n\\tat io.grpc.Context.run(Context.java:536)\\n\\tat com.google.tracing.GenericContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(GenericContextCallback.java:75)\\n\\tat com.google.common.context.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:74)\\n\\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)\\n\\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)\\n\\tat com.google.apps.framework.server.AbstractThreadPoolModule$InitializingThreadFactory.lambda$newThread$0(AbstractThreadPoolModule.java:416)\\n\\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)\\n\\n\"\n",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

Thanks you very much for your attention. Any help to fix the issue is appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to supply the [Request body](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.webTokens/create#request-body) of the [enterprises.webTokens.create](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.webTokens/create) method. The request body contains an instance of [WebToken](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.webTokens#WebToken).

**Request body:**

```
{
  "parentFrameUrl": "<the URL of the page that will be hosting the iFrame>",
  "enabledFeatures": [
    "PLAY_SEARCH",
    "PRIVATE_APPS",
    "WEB_APPS",
    "STORE_BUILDER"
  ],
 "permissions": [
    "APPROVE_APPS"
  ]
}
```

If successful, the response body contains a newly created *instance* of [WebToken](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.webTokens#WebToken) containing the value you need to embed the **iFrame** on the hosting page.

Comment: HI @rey V.Aquino, I tried with this but it not seems working and giving the same error. You can see this link https://developers.google.com/android/management/apps#managed_google_play_iframe . We are following but it's not working. Did we missed anything?

Comment: It's working on my end. Ensure that the `parentFrameUrl` is **'https'** to prevent **cross-site scripting** attacks. The iframe may not be hosted at other URLs. Https must be used for the URL.

Comment: Thank you, You have made my day @Rey V. Aquino, I just missed the 'https' part.

Comment: Hi @Rey V. Aquino, after implementing managed google play store, where I just passed "parentFrameUrl". When I'm visiting Search Play Store -> selecting any app -> then it showing "Select" button instead of "Approve" or "Un-approve" button. Could you please help me out on this?

Comment: You can refer to the [**URL  parameters**](https://developers.google.com/android/management/apps#url_parameters) for more information. This will help you to customize your iframe.

Comment: Hi @Rey V. Aquino, Can you please tell me the use of "Select", is it the replacement of "Approve"? Then why approve and unapprove button is showing. If "select button" is the new thing. I'm following this link: https://developers.google.com/android/management/apps#managed_google_play_iframe

Comment: I'm getting package name on onproductselect event. But if I'm approving then how to get the packageName, action and productId.                                                                                       onproductselect work in this                                        
 iframe.register('onproductselect', function(event) {
  console.log(event);
}, gapi.iframes.CROSS_ORIGIN_IFRAMES_FILTER);

Comment: Is the Approve feature is deprecated as mentioned in https://developers.google.com/android/management/apps#url_parameters? Then on clicking "select" nothing is happening. I expected on the app I click "select" button the button text should be turned to "Selected" and the app should be installed in Managed Play Store.                                         
                                  APPROVE (default): lets IT admins select, approve, and un-approve apps. This mode is deprecated, use SELECT instead. APPROVE mode only works if PlaySearch.ApproveApps is set to true in the web token.

Comment: **SELECT** is not actually a replacement for **APPROVE**. A Select button will appear when you added URL parameter `mode=SELECT` and click feature apps on your manage Google Play iframe. You can find out the `packageName` of an app by clicking the **Select Button**. When the URL parameter `mode=APPROVE` is chosen, the **Approve button** will appear. Upon approval of an app, a pop-up appears where you can modify the app's approval settings, you will see the buttons **Select**, **Unapprove**, and **Approval Settings** when you revisit the app you approved recently.

Comment: If I set `mode=APPROVE` then upon approval, how I fetch the `packageName`? Getting `packageName` became easy if `mode=SELECT` as for this there is an event `onproductselect` event. So, what's the event is dedicated for 'mode=APPROVE'? As I need to show the user `Approve` option when the user click on it, the respective app will be installed on the device and when clicking on`Unapprove` the app will be uninstalled.

Comment: Using the App Approval action no longer makes sense since the app is automatically Approved when you include it on a policy.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to inject the `Approve` action into a policy? Currently, when I'm clicking on `Approve` button it's only reflection on web Managed Play Store, here is the link [play.google.com/work/licenses/apps](https://play.google.com/work/licenses/apps). But it's **not installing** the **approved app** on the device which I'm expecting. Where the device is already enrolled with same enterprise (in the enterprise id where web managed play store apps are showing).

Comment: `Regarding the policy`, Lemme first tell you that I'm following QR based provisioning method. So, when I'm generating enrollment token at that time I'm injecting a policy to the token. Then I'm generating a QR code based on the enrollment token, and the device scan that QR code to enroll itself with the specified enterprise having a policy.

Comment: `In the web managed playstore` when I'm `Approving` any app it's only reflecting to the `My Managed Apps` section of the [web managed playstore](https://play.google.com/work/licenses/apps) but it's `not installing the approved app` on the enrolled device that I shared with you on the above reply.

Comment: Hi Rey, Have you implemented Zerotouch Enrollment? While calling customer related APIs, I'm getting error of ToS (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72788750/zero-touch-customer-api-terms-of-service-error-403-permission-denied). Please check the link and let me know if you have any suggestions.